# Can someone provide me a regex for DOB that matches either 1986-04-02 OR XXXX-XX-XX

Tags: regex

DOBs that I want to accept are:

```
XXXX-04-26(1976-04-26)
1976-XX-26(1976-04-26)
1976-04-XX(1976-04-26)
```

I am not a regex expert. Currently, I have

```
[RegularExpression("^(((\\d{4}-((0[13578]-|1[02]-)(0[1-9]|[12]\\d|3[01])|(0[13456789]-|1[012]-)(0[1-9]|[12]\\d|30)|02-(0[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])))|((([02468][048]|[13579][26])00|\\d{2}([13579][26]|0[48]|[2468][048])))-02-29)){0,10}$", ErrorMessage = "next_court_date is invalid and date format should be 'YYYY-MM-DD'")]
```

which matches the date  expression, but I need to add the second expression to it as an alternative.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like there was a copy/paste issue. Please fix the question.

Answer (score 0):

This regex:

`(?:[0-9]|X){4}-(?:[0-9]|X){2}-(?:[0-9]|X){2}`

finds XXXX-XX-XX as well as 1997-02-92 and all of its combinations, but the groups (separated by the dash) have to be either a group of X or a number.

Basically it sais:
group of four of numbers or X, a dash, group of two of numbers or X, a dash, group of two of numbers or X

Answer (score 0):

```
(XXXX|[1-2]\d{3})-(XX|(0[1-9])|1(1|2))-(XX|([0-2]\d)|30|31)$
```

here is a demo in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cv9Fka/4)